# C#: Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to access a stored procedure that retrieves a page using an id.

But I am getting an error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<StorePageCMS.Models.mn_StorePage_Select_One_Result>' to 'StorePageCMS.Models.StorePage'
```

I am not sure how to fix this. The stored precedure that comes from dbEntities from SQL Server, does take an int parameter.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    public StorePage Get(int StorePageID)
    {
        using (dbEntities db = new dbEntities())
        {
            StorePage storepage = db.mn_StorePage_Select_One(StorePageID);

            if (storepage == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }
            return storepage;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I rewrote the method this way:

```
    public List<StorePage> Get(int StorePageID)
    {
        List<StorePage> storepagelist = new List<StorePage>();

        using (dbEntities db = new dbEntities())
        {
            var results = db.mn_StorePage_Select_One(StorePageID).ToList();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                var storepage = new StorePage()
                {

                    StorePageID = result.StorePageID,
                    SPPreambleID = result.SPPreambleID,
                    Title = result.Title,
                    SEOTitle = result.SEOTitle,
                    ParentStorePageID = result.ParentStorePageID ?? -1,
                    Meta = result.Meta,
                    Image = result.Image,
                    ImageLink = result.ImageLink,
                    Blurb = result.Blurb,
                    RegionID = result.RegionID,
                    Footer = result.Footer
                };
                storepagelist.Add(storepage);
            }
            return storepagelist;
        }
    }
```

Does this looks more correct?

**2 UPDATE**

Does this looks correct?

[image]

Comment: You cannot call a database query directly into a class. You need to physically transfer the items from the database fields into the class properties or use serialization or reflection. Please Google "C-sharp sql datareader" and the other keywords I used here for some ideas

Comment: check your DataContext file or how is that called right I am not sure, and you have to change return type of your stored procedure,try this: `StorePageCMS.Models.mn_StorePage_Select_One_Result storepage = db.mn_StorePage_Select_One(StorePageID);`

Comment: I added an update, could you please give me your feedback as to whether that method is closer to how it is supposed to work? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Code First model of Entity Framework? It appears not, though we need to know. `StorePageCMS.Models.mn_StorePage_Select_One_Result` has no conversion to `StorePage`. If that's a stored procedure result, you need to map it's result to the `StorePage` model instead in the EDMX designer.

Comment: Is your proc returning 1 record or more than 1.  The name implies that you are returning 1, Therefore it is a collection of 1 record (with many fields). You will not be able to create a list from one record. It seems like you are confusing 1 record of many fields with a DataSet/dataTable of multiple records of 1 field.

Comment: You should redefine your model Function Import to return an Entities type if it matches and entity or otherwise a  or otherwise Complex type

Comment: @erasmocarlos did you get it working? Doing what is proposed below (3 hours ago) should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi TylerY86, I apologize for not getting back to you before, I got taken away from this task at the end of the day, and today I will be getting back to it a bit later tough. I will post an update as soon as I have something to report. Many thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the Code First model of Entity Framework
Since `StorePageCMS.Models.mn_StorePage_Select_One_Result` has no conversion to `StorePage`, I'm assuming it's a stored procedure result. If that's a stored procedure result (of `mn_StorePage_Select_One`), you need to map it's result to the `StorePage` model instead in the EDMX designer.

[image: Edit Function Import screenshot]

Here, you'd need to say it returns a collection of `StorePageCMS.Models.StorePage` Entities.

Comment: I added a screen shot of what I did. I have not tested it.

Comment: Change the "Returns a Collection Of" to Entities, and set it to `StorePageCMS.Models.StorePage`. It has to actually map to that entity correctly, but it looks like it might.